# Single word for "embrace and extend and possibly corrupt ideas of a political movement"

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a single word for the process in which political parties (or other groups that have something to gain) embrace and extend (and maybe corrupt) the ideas of a political movement that started and grew outside of the regular channels? Recuperate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a term covering disparate ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you want the word *co-opt*.

Merriam-Webster gives:

> a :  to take into a group (as a faction, movement, or culture) :  absorb, assimilate. *the students are co–opted by a system they serve even in their struggle against it* — A. C. Danto
>
> b :  take over, appropriate. *a style co–opted by advertisers*

*Appropriate* (as a verb, pronounced with a long final *a*, to rhyme with *state*) may also serve your purpose.

*Recuperate* is almost always used to mean "to recover from an illness".  Its alternate meaning of "to recover something that was lost" doesn't fit here either.  Merriam-Webster also gives "to bring back into use or currency :  revive" but that seems very uncommon, and is no better.

Comment: And major political parties the world over are very good at co-opting movements that threaten to split their core of support. This may be more pronounced in the US where the "winner takes all" structure of electrons casuses a tendency toward having exactly two major parties at any given time.

Comment: @dmckee: The structure of **electrons**?  Well, you're the particle physicist, so I'll take your word for it...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to focus on the "corrupt" portion, you could use *[bastardize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bastardize)*:

> to modify especially by introducing discordant or disparate elements
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bastardize)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Also to **to adopt** may fit you description:

- *To take up and make one's own: adopt a new idea.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[**pick up**](http://www.flowofhistory.com/readings-flowcharts/the-early-modern-era/the-age-revolutions/fc106)" and "[**seize upon**](http://www.cordobainitiative.org/islamic_rule_of_law/)."